# How do I add a structure inside a class ? C Sharp to objective c language translation

Tags: c#, iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have made a class library for Windows Mobile in C# that uses a Web Service, now I want to create one for iPhone development.  And I need to keep the same class structures in all of the libraries. In C# I have class structures that look like this

```
public class Access
{
       public const long Version = 1;
       public long  Checker;
       public class Data
       { 
             public long AcountId;
             public string SessionKeys;
       }
}
```

I know that in Objective C class structures inside class are not permitted. But I want to know the best way to mimic or copy this class structure. I added objects of Data class inside Access Class but I'm tot sure that it's the best way. Anybody knows a better way or any ideas please tell. 
Oh and if someone knows a depth-in in Objective C pointer or class structure tutorial please leave a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your best bet is to just create 2 classes: `Access` and `Access_Data`.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is known as Nested Classes.
See this [forum post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2009/Apr/msg00202.html) for some help on how to mimic them in Objective C.

Comment: Close to what i'm looking for but not quite.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to keep it as nested classes? Does the inner class have behavior or is it just data? If you don't need Access.Data to have behavior (e.g.):

```
typedef struct _AccessData {
    long       AccoountId;
    NSString   sessionKeys;
} AccessData;

@interface Access: NSObject {
    .
    .
    AccessData  Data; 
}
@end
```

Comment: I have to implement methods to